# Adding Values in Custom Product Attribute From the Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-attribute

I am creating one module for the custom product attribute and i want to add values in dropdown from the database.

I am using this code for adding vaules in dropdown:

```
public function getOptionText($value) {
    $value = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_wri‌​te');
    $result = $value->query("select * from upload_image_upload");
    while ($row = $result->fetch() ) {
        $ids[]=$row['image'];
    }
    $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == $value) {
            return $item['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us in detail what you have tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add values in to dropdown attribute from the database table rather than this "value 1", "value 2" etc..

Comment: can you help me please?

Comment: do you want code for that or you want to add directly in database?

Comment: Though source model you can add options.This source model call in to your setup file " https://www.envisionecommerce.com/how-to-programmatically-create-attribute-type-drop-down-in-magento-2/" see this may it will usefull not sure

Comment: i want to code for that @ Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: public function getOptionText($value)
 
    {
  $value = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
  $result = $value->query("select * from upload_image_upload");
  while ($row = $result->fetch() )
  {
   $ids[]=$row['image'];

  }
        $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);

        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if ($item['value'] == $value) {
                return $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;    }

Comment: i am using this code for adding vaules in dropdown

Comment: And what is your code for `getAllOptions()`? This method is the one that's used to populate the dropdown. Please show your complete source model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code

where `$option` contains array like this

`$options[0]= array("label"=>$label,'value'=>$value)`

```
$attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
$attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
$attribute->setData('option',$option);
    $attribute->save();
```

Comment: i do not want to add data like above code. i want to add data in dropdown from the other table like "upload_image_upload".means fetch data from this table and that fetched data should be add as value in dropdown attribute

Comment: So this is your duplicate question as before??

Comment: yes i have face this problem from last week . can you help me ?

Comment: Dont ask same question again and again if you had try anything then post otherwise there is no mean to ask same question again and again

Comment: oh... than you can tell me that you have no idea about this.

Comment: i dont mind....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to add values. But if you want to add with database you have to add values in 2 tables 'eav_attribute_option' and 'eav_attribute_option_value'.